# Why Is String Formatting Causing a Casting Exception?

Tags: clojure

Why does `(String/format "%8s" (Integer/toBinaryString 6))` result in a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object` casting exception?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know Clojure, but I *suspect* that's trying to call the method as if it were the Java:

```
String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(6));
```

but *without* the varargs support. I *suspect* you want:

```
(String/format "%8s" (into-array Object (Integer/toBinaryString 6)))
```

See [this mailing list thread](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/64b20acf76e2b687) for more information from people who actually *do* know Clojure :)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the issue. A better solution than using `String/format` and `into-array` is to just use the Clojure function `format`, which takes varargs Clojure-style and otherwise behaves the same as `String/format`.

Comment: @amalloy: Indeed, as noted on the mailing list thread. I didn't want to get too far off the track of what I thought I'd be able to get away with in terms of correct code :)