# How to cast explicitly in clojure when interfacing with java

Tags: java, clojure, interop, variadic-functions

In trying to use weka from clojure, I'm trying to convert [this howto guide](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Programmatic+Use) from the weka wiki to clojure using the java interop features of clojure.

This has worked well so far, except in one case, where the clojure reflection mechanism can't seem to find the right method to invoke - I have:

```
(def c-model (doto (NaiveBayes.) (.buildClassifier is-training-set)))
```

Later this will be invoked by the `.evaluateModel` method of the `Evaluation` class:

```
(.evaluateModel e-test c-model is-testing-set)
```

where `e-test` is of type `weka.classifiers.Evaluation` and, according to [their api documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html#evaluateModel%28weka.classifiers.Classifier,%20weka.core.Instances,%20java.lang.Object...%29) the method takes two parameters of types `Classifier` and `Instances`

What I get from clojure though is `IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: evaluateModel for class weka.classifiers.Evaluation  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:53)` - I guess that this is because `c-model` is actually of type `NaiveBayes`, although it should also be a `Classifier` - which it is, according to `instance?`.

I tried casting with `cast` to no avail, and from what I understand this is more of a type assertion (and passes without problems, of course) than a real cast in clojure. Is there another way of explicitly telling clojure which types to cast to in java interop method calls? (Note that the original guide I linked above also uses an explicit cast from `NaiveBayes` to `Classifier`)

Full code here: /http://paste.lisp.org/display/129250

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The linked javadoc contradicts your claim that there is a method taking a Classifier and an Instances - what there is, is a method taking a Classifier, an Instances, *and a variable number of Objects*. As discussed in a number of SO questions (the only one of which I can find at the moment is [Why Is String Formatting Causing a Casting Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643151/why-is-string-formatting-causing-a-casting-exception)), Clojure does not provide implicit support for varargs, which are basically fictions created by the `javac` compiler. At the JVM level, it is simply an additional required parameter of type Object[]. If you pass a third parameter, an empty object-array, into your method, it will work fine.

Comment: i was wondering about what to do with the varargs for a second, but didn't come across that answer - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`IllegalArgumentException No matching method found` happens anytime the arguments don't match the class. They can fail to match because no method exists with that name and number of arguments or because no method exists with that name in the called class. so also check the number and type of the arguments.

I basically always resort to repl-utils/show in these cases

Comment: that the arguments don't match is what i have also found, the thing is i have already checked their type with `instance?` and that does all I want - only the interpreter does something else on method invocation :( Regarding repl-utils/show: I get a bunch of warnings when `use`ing the `clojure-contrib` library (version 1.2) that i found on clojars.org and the show function throws an error - it doesn't seem to play well with clojure 1.4

Comment: In clojure 1.3 and higher, the text-based `show` has been replaced by the data-driven function `clojure.reflect/reflect`.